# two shifts for one day but only one driver and one taxi car for that shift

Tags: sql

First I don't know much about sql only basic things. I need help about how to implement a program. I have created two tables: Drivers and Cars. 
IDDriver
IDCar 
I need help about how to implement this scenario:

I need to create stored procedures for: creation, updating and deletion of one shift.
In one day must be two shifts: one car for the two shifts but only one driver for shift.

Any help?

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You also need to expand your data model to include shifts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a schema somthing like this

```
CREATE TABLE [Driver]
(
      [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [Car]
(
      [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [Registration] NVARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [ShiftType]
(
      [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [StartTime] TIME NOT NULL
    , [StartDayOfWeek] TINYINT NOT NULL
    , [EndTime] TIME NOT NULL
    , [EndDayOfWeek] TINYINT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [Shift]
(
      [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , [DriverId] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [Driver]([Id])
    , [CarId] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [Car]([Id])
    , [ShiftId] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [Shift]([Id])
)
```

You can insert some basic data like this

```
INSERT [Driver] VALUES ('Bob')
INSERT [Car] VALUES ('ABC1234')
INSERT [ShiftType] VALUES ('08:00:00', 0, '20:00:00', 0)
INSERT [ShiftType] VALUES ('20:00:00', 0, '08:00:00', 1)
INSERT [Shift] VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT [Shift] VALUES (1, 1, 2)
```

and get it out like this

```
SELECT
              [D].*
            , [C].*
            , [ST].*   
    FROM
            [Shift] [S]
        JOIN
            [Driver] [D]
                ON [D].[Id] = [S].[DriverId]
        JOIN
            [Car] [C]
                ON [C].[Id] = [S].[CarId]
        JOIN
            [ShiftType] [ST]
                ON [ST].[Id] = [S].[ShiftTypeId]
```

[Here it is on fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4d48/2)

---

This should give you a good starting point to have a go at some stored procedures yourself and post any attempts in a well structured question.